# Overriding/Overloading of interface methods

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

If a concrete class extends an abstract class which implements an interface in java is it possible to overload any of the methods from the interface more in the concrete class?

Comment: Why won't you check it?

Comment: Yes you can, but you are not overriding, you are only overloading

Comment: Overload and override are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can override it with any parameter(s) you want, as long as you implement it aswell with the specified parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Interface fully defines function (including parameter types). So if you override with different parameters you actually implements new function which is not known to interface IMHO.